# asyncio - Catch timeout for asyncio.wait

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I am using `asyncio` with `python3.5.1` and I have a utility function that makes sync methods to async ones. I pass multiple blocking functions and wait for their results for a timeout. I use timeout becuase, I don't want to block whole process.

Lets assume, we have system searches something. It searches on different datasources and merges the results into one and response it to end-user in milliseconds. Not to block our end-users for a specific time(timeout), I want to put some timeout each search source. I've done that with the code below. But my question is that, is there a way to handle that timeout issues and generate some kind of email alarm or etc. Because I want to monitor them and to try to figure out whats going on while my endusers have no problem about system search speed. I prefer to ignore a bit of accuracy instead of doing search so slow. Slowing issue may kill us.

```python
def run_blocking_tasks(func_with_args, wait=False, timeout=None):
    async def _execute(func_with_args, wait, timeout):
        logger.debug('creating executor tasks')
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(func_with_args),)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        blocking_tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, func_call[0], *func_call[1]) for func_call in func_with_args]
        logger.debug('waiting for executor tasks')
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(blocking_tasks, timeout=timeout, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
        if wait:
            return [t.result() for t in completed]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(_execute(func_with_args, wait, timeout))
```

I call this function as;

```python
run_blocking_tasks(
 [
  (fast_source1.search, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
  (fast_source2.search, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
  (slow_source1.search, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
],timeout=1.0)
```

This code will run properly. It will response in time as our timeout regardlessly what happened to my sources. But my need is to do something, (maybe logging it into database or email it I don't know), on timeout occurs.

I saw `asyncio.wait_for` but I guess, it cancels everything and raise TimeourError. I don't want ot cancel anything. I want my successful result responed in time to present it to my end-users as guarantied a time.

Comment: what about catching the TimeourError ?

Comment: `asyncio.wait` does not raise `TimeoutError`. It just responses for the ones which is completed in time.

Comment: raises asyncio.TimeoutError. To avoid the task cancellation, wrap it in shield()

Comment: Even I wrap the `future` generated by `run_in_executor` with `shield` and `asyncio.wait_for`, I get `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError`.